# How to deploy Flask App into existing VirtualHost as wsgi on apache2?

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm struggling on deploying a Flask app into an existing VirtualHost configuration. I'd like to keep all web applications under the same domain on the same port. When following the majority of tutorials it work's without problems:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:81>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"

</IfModule> 
SSLProxyEngine On

    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias /flasktest /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/static
    <Directory /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/fullchain.pem
```

But when I try to integrate this into existing config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost own_domain:443>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"

</IfModule> 
SSLProxyEngine On

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>


BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown


DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /flasktest /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/static
    <Directory /var/www/SetImageText/SetImageText/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


<Directory /var/www/owncloud>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/own_domain/fullchain.pem
```

It will only answer with 404. Does someone know a possibility to integrate this wsgi stuff into an existing Virtualhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My virtual host file isn't as complex as yours but I was able to get my Flask app working (integrating WSGIScriptAlias into my existing virtual host file) by following the example from the mod_wsgi docs.

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Specifically the sample virtual host configuration in the section "Mounting the WSGI Application".

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents

    <Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I found the solution myself. @HanibalG didn't give the explicit solution but his config example contains it. I had to replace my `<VirtualHost own_domain:443>` with a wildcard `<VirtualHost *:443>` .